# DataReader result truncated when reading from StreamSocket

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8, microsoft-metro, imap

I have the following c# / WinRT code to receive a response from an IMAP command

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(sock.InputStream);
reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
await reader.LoadAsync(1000000);
string data = string.Empty;
while(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0){
    data += reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
}
```

The results are truncated after 8192 bytes. 8192 looks suspiciously like a limit of some kind. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The abstraction of TCP/IP sockets is a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), as I explain on my blog. So it's perfectly normal to have a partial `LoadAsync` return after a partial message or any number of messages.

8192 sounds like it could be a jumbo frame (Gigabit Ethernet). Or perhaps the default read size of some .NET layer.

Anyway, what you're seeing is perfectly normal and acceptable for TCP/IP communications. You have to loop on `LoadAsync` (and `ReadString`) until you detect the end of your message. I think IMAP uses linefeeds, at least for *some* of its message delimeters. Normally, you'd have to handle situations where your message would end in the middle of a string, but I *think* may might be able to skip this check for IMAP.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I figured I needed to loop on LoadAsync alright but on what condition? `while` what?

Comment: Until you have a complete message. The IMAP protocol should define what a "complete message" is - I'm not sure for that protocol.

Comment: IMAP Responds with a line starting with * OK to designate the end of a "complete message". Before WinRT I could use ReadLine() to return a line and test it. However, now I can only read a string of a certain length. All examples suggest using `reader.UnconsumedBufferLength`, but this is shorter than the message I'm reading, and if I try and loop over the read code it all just hangs

Comment: You just have to continue looping until you see a line starting with * OK. There is no built-in `ReadLineAsync`.

Comment: I had tried looping over the response a number of times and was getting infinite loops. Finally I tried going one at a time, incrementally increasing. Turns out I was literally checking for `* OK` when * should have been the command numeber. Thanks for the continued patience.