# How can I accept "unsafe" HTTP response headers in a Windows Phone/Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Recently, some code in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app that used `HttpClient` to access a 3rd-party REST API stopped working.
I got the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

After trying this in Windows Phone (Silverlight) and Store (RT) apps, I rewrote the same code in WPF and finally got a useful error message:

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF"

There is also a [great in-depth blog post](http://mehdi.me/a-tale-of-debugging-the-linkedin-api-net-and-http-protocol-violations/) about this problem.

Microsoft has stated that they [will not fix/allow this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5a8f4b30-a91a-407f-aa6e-7be6ff68a152/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-of-httpclient) so I'm either forced to find a 3rd-party HTTP library that will allow unsafe headers or write my own.

How can I solve this problem? If I write my own library from scratch, what would be the appropriate classes to consider? Is there any relevant sample code available?

(This question might be too similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580016/httpclient-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responseheader-detail) although after writing some test code, the idea of using a custom handler with `HttpClient` doesn't work either since the [system handler is called first](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/httpclient-message-handlers) on response.)

Comment: This is a good question, but with current title and "such a library exist" it will probably be closed as off-topic "recommend or find  libraries, tools ..". May be you can change the phrasing a bit?

Comment: Report as bug to the "third party"?

Comment: @MikkoViitala I did a month ago; they still haven't fixed it. See the MSDN link that points out that consuming GoPro (and other data) also gives the same problem. We need a client-side solution to this problem I think.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thanks for the advice; I've updated my question and hopefully it's more acceptable now. Let me know if you have any more advice for re-phrasing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can implement a basic HTTP client fairly easily. Ignoring error handling and dealing with `Content-Length` (more on that later), this code should do the trick.

```
var hostname = new HostName("www.w3.org");
var socket = new StreamSocket();
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostname, "80");

var request = "GET /Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
          "Host: www.w3.org\r\n" +
          "\r\n";

var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
writer.WriteString(request);
await writer.StoreAsync();

var reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

string data = string.Empty;    
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

bool doneReading = false;
uint bytesToRead = 10240;

while (!doneReading)
{
  try
  {
    cts.CancelAfter(10 * 1000);
    await reader.LoadAsync(bytesToRead).AsTask(cts.Token);
    data += reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException)
  {
    doneReading = true;
  }
}

socket.Dispose();
```

There are definitely some issues to solve:

- The timeout is 10 seconds. But depending on what kind of connection you're on, perhaps that's ok?
- For that matter, waiting for a timeout is the wrong way to determine if the server has finished sending data. As Jon Skeet mentioned in [Correctly receiving data using StreamSocket hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206804/correctly-receiving-data-using-streamsocket-hangs), the client should read `Content-Length` from the header and request the appropriate number of bytes. Of course, since [TCP is a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842662/9913) this takes a bit of work as well.

Also, this solution is mainly for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. Although it will also work on Windows Phone 8.1/Windows Store (i.e. WinRT) apps, it might be easier to use `MessageWebSocket` on that platform.

I wrote a three-part series of posts on this since it appears to be a fairly common issue; this work-around is discussed in [part two](http://www.jedidja.ca/dealing-with-a-protocol-violation-on-wp-8-1/). Also of note is that the error message `CR must be followed by LF` [may not be completely accurate](http://www.jedidja.ca/the-protocol-violation-with-the-misleading-error-message/) -- it could also means there's an invalid character in the header (including a space in one of the header names).